# mongodb return fields optionally

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "abcdefg",
  "status" : 1,
  "myData": {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : "zxcvbnm",
  "status" : 3,
  "myData": {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  }
}
```

if "status" === 3, field "myData" will return, like

```
myCollection.find({}, {"status": 1, "myData": 1})
```

if "status" !== 3, field "myData" will not return, like:

```
myCollection.find({}, {"status": 1, "myData": 0})
```

How could I do that in mongodb?

Comment: You really cannot. The only thing where you could make such an assertion is using `mapReduce`, and that's overkill for this purpose. The best approach is to apply your condition to each returned result and modify each returned document from the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You could set them to null with aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        status: 1,
        myData: {
            $cond: [{
                $eq: ['$status', 1]
            }, '$myData', null]
        }
    }
})
```

It does not remove the field but saves you some traffic.